# How to change the input shape of model in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have a model that I load this way:

```
def YOLOv3_pretrained(n_classes=12, n_bbox=3):

yolo3 = tf.keras.models.load_model("yolov3/yolo3.h5")
yolo3.trainable = False
l3 = yolo3.get_layer('leaky_re_lu_71').output
l3_flat = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(l3)
out3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100*(4+1+n_classes))(l3_flat)
out3 = Reshape((100, (4+1+n_classes)), input_shape=(12,))(out3)
yolo3 = Model(inputs=yolo3.input, outputs=[out3])
return yolo3
```

I want to add a Dense at the end of it but since it takes an input with shape (None, 416,416,3) it doesn't let me do it and it returns an error:

```
ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to a Dense layer should be defined. Found None. Full input shape received: (None, None)
```

I also tried this way with a Sequential (I want to use just the last output of yolo):

```
def YOLOv3_Dense(n_classes=12):

yolo3 = tf.keras.models.load_model("yolov3/yolo3.h5")

model = Sequential()
model.add(yolo3)
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100*(4+1+n_classes)))
model.add(Reshape((100, (4+1+n_classes)), input_shape=(413,413,3)))
return model
```

But it returns another error:

```
ValueError: All layers in a Sequential model should have a single output tensor. For multi-output layers, use the functional API.
```

Is there a way to add the final Dense layer?

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried?

Comment: I just added it.

Comment: Is there a way to fix the output shape?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it's from [this](https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3/blob/master/convert.py). I ran this script and got as output the model.h5.
If you need it (so that you don't have to run all of that) you can find it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fxor8fR0Zr1MdYwcEYwwfwjfYNAHsYgZ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: That has nothing to do with your question but why are you using Yolov3 when the v5 is existing ?

Comment: Long story but basically I'm writing an object detector from scratch and yolov5 is too complex to be written from zero. That's why I choose yolov3 initally. Now I changed plans since I couldn't reproduce the original Loss so I'm taking the yolo I have and I will add this Dense at the end for my final experiment. This is for a university project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to reduce (flatten) an output with multiple `None` dimensions, which will not work if you want to use the output as input to another layer. You can try using a `GlobalAveragePooling2D` or `GlobalMaxPooling2D` instead:

```
import tensorflow as tf

yolo3 = tf.keras.models.load_model("yolo3.h5")
yolo3.trainable = False
l3 = yolo3.get_layer('leaky_re_lu_71').output
l3_flat = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()(l3)
out3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100*(4+1+12))(l3_flat)
out3 = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((100, (4+1+12)), input_shape=(12,))(out3)
yolo3 = tf.keras.Model(inputs=yolo3.input, outputs=[out3])
```